# Is "all" used as an adverb to modify the following adjective?

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

> ...But, as all cat lovers know, sometimes our otherwise friendly felines will bite us when we're trying to pet them, which makes no sense at all. 
>   Why get **all** bitey with the human who loves them, feeds them, and passive-aggressively scoops their litter box? ...

does the word "**all**" mean "very"?

like this:

> LONGMAN Dictionary:
>
> SPOKEN PHRASES
>
> 14 very
>
> You’re getting me all confused.

here is a sentence I made:

> Why did you get all angry with your parents who love you.

is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does mean “very” in the example you quoted as well as your own sentence. However, in the sentence you gave, it’s more akin to *so*, as in *why did you get so angry with your parents who love you?*

Saying “why did you get very angry...” sounds awkward to me, though it’s technically grammatically correct.